# Why I get the error message that my custom logging handler "has no attribute `level`"?

Tags: python

I have the following handler:

```py
import logging 
from peewee import * 

db = SqliteDatabase("my_app.db") 

class Log(Model): 
    message = CharField() 
    class Meta: 
        database = db 

Log.create_table(db) 

class DatabaseHandler(logging.Handler): 
    def emit(self, record): 
        try: 
            event = Log( 
                message=record.message 
            ) 
            event.save() 

        except Exception: 
            self.handleError(record)
```

And when I do:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(DatabaseHandler)
logger.info("something")
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/home/raf/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1383, in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/raf/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1519, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/home/raf/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1529, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/home/raf/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1590, in callHandlers
    if record.levelno >= hdlr.level:
AttributeError: type object 'DatabaseHandler' has no attribute 'level'
```

I only could find this error in one other place (https://github.com/GNS3/gns3-gui/issues/2109) and it has no solution.

It's probably because I wrote the handler incorrectly, I'd appreciate it if anyone could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly pointed out by @polar_bear, `DatabaseHandler` needs to be instantiated before being passed to `addHandler`. Another problem was accessing `record.message` when you should be accessing `record.msg` ([someone found this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408496/python-logging-handler-to-append-to-list/36411214#comment60463311_36408692)).

Here's the corrected code:

```py
import logging 
from peewee import * 

db = SqliteDatabase("my_app.db") 

class Log(Model): 
    message = CharField() 
    class Meta: 
        database = db 

Log.create_table(db) 

class DatabaseHandler(logging.Handler): 
    def emit(self, record): 
      try: 
          event = Log( 
              message=record.msg
          ) 
          event.save() 

      except Exception: 
          self.handleError(record)

dh = DatabaseHandler()

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) 
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 
logger.addHandler(dh)
logger.info("something")
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! And do you why I have to do `record.msg`? Judging by (https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-objects) `message` should be the attribute and `msg` an argument of a LogRecord. Does this mean `record` is not yet instantiated when it's passed to `emit` function?

Comment: Great question! Python source code to the rescue :-) It seems that the `message` attribute gets set on the record in the record's formatter's `format()` method call -- [see here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L664). So: `msg` is the "real", initial message, while `message` is the human-readable representation of it which does get set (some point after emit). It also makes sense, as `msg` is formatted using `args` -- `message` is the end result of that formatting -- [see here under `msg`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes))

Comment: ... which also means that you might want to do `message=record.msg % record.args` :-)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell you are trying to inherit in DatabaseHandler the Handler object.

The official documentation states:
"Note that Handler is never instantiated directly; this class acts as a base for more useful subclasses. However, the **init**() method in subclasses needs to call Handler.**init**()."
As far as I can tell you should initialise the the handler in your class.

Comment: You mean something like this?
```
class DatabaseHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

...
```
I still get the same error message though.